# How to retrieve data from Database by clicking on button using Post Method?

Tags: php, database, menu

The first query is used to load main menu itens.
Each menu itens has its id, I need to pass this id to ajax function in order to retrieve data to a specified div, in case this div is on the page named as
menu name.

```
$SQL_MENU ="SELECT  id_menu,menu_name FROM  dbo.menu WHERE  (menu_active = 1)";
$exec_menu = @mssql_query($SQL_MENU);

<?php while ($row = @mssql_fetch_array($exec_menu))
{ ?>  
    <div class="ui-content-btn">
    <a href="new.php?tipo=<?php echo $row['id_menu'] ?>" id="<?php echo $row['id_menu'] ?>"  value ="<?php $row['id_menu'] ?>" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">  <?php echo $row['menu_name'] ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which element would you point to run the ajax function? element "a" ?

```
<a identity="{this id}" onclick="my_function(this);" href="new.php?..">
```

Javascript:

```
function my_function(e){
   var myid   = e.getAttribute('identity');
   var myhref = e.getAttribute('href');
   //ajax here //
}
```

Is that what you mean ?